# How to go calendar app from my app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to go calendar app from my app, but I don't know to how.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("Calendar"));
   activity.startActivity(intent);
```

I think that is like this code but no work.
Any idea?

I hope that somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

try the following,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  

intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");

intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");

intent.putExtra("beginTime", eventStartInMillis);

intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I don't need to integrate Calendar.Only to show Calendar.